# Add Background color after setting content in input field

Tags: html, css

Is there any way that i could add a background color after placing a content inside an input field? Just like what happens when an autocomplete works.

Thanks!

Comment: try using `input:focus` in CSS

Comment: I did try using focus however, i want the background color to stay as long as  there is content present and disappears when there is none.

Comment: Put on your code in jsfiddle

Comment: Please provide the HTML for your `input` tag, at least.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you could achieve this. You could make the `input` mandatory by adding the [`required` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-required). Doing this means that as soon as the user enters anything into the field, it is now in the valid state and you can target it in your CSS using the [`:valid` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:valid):

```css
input:valid{
  background:#ff9;
}
```

```html
<input required>
```

Or, if you don't want to make the field mandatory and as others have suggested, you could set the new `background-color` when the field receives focus. To prevent it from reverting to its initial color when it loses focus, you will need to add a `transition` to the `background`, setting the `transition-delay` to some ridiculously high number when the `input` is in its normal state and resetting it to `0s` when it is focused. Obviously, though, this change will occur whether or not the user actually enters anything in the field or not.

```css
input{
  transition-delay:9999s;
  transition-property:background;
}
input:focus{
  background:#ff9;
  transition-delay:0s;
}
```

```html
<input>
```

If neither of those options suit your needs then you will probably need to resort to using JavaScript to add or remove a class, depending on whether or not the `value` of the `input` is empty.

```js
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("input",function(){
  this.value?this.classList.add("filled"):this.classList.remove("filled");
},0);
```

```css
.filled{
  background:#ff9;
}
```

```html
<input>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Html**

```
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname">
```

**Css**

```
 input:focus {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
```

[Demo in JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/kvgc8w7a/)

Comment: did try using focus however, i want the background color to stay as long as there is content present and disappears when there is none.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Jquery**,

```
$( "#target" ).blur(function() {
    $( "#target" ).css('background-color','red');
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/kvgc8w7a/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with pure javascript

```js
var input = document.getElementById("test");
input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  if (input.value)
    input.style.backgroundColor = '#90EE90';
  else
    input.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
});
```

```html
<input id="test" type="text" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a Css class like

```
.myCSSClass
{
background-color:red;
}
```

Now using jquery on blur function you add this class

```
$("#myTextBox").on('blur',function(){
if($("#myTextBox").val()==""){
  if($("#myTextBox").hasClass("myCSSClass")){
    $("#myTextBox").removeClass("myCSSClass");
  }
}
else
{
$("#myTextBox").addClass("myCSSClass")
}
});
```